# Rows cannot be programmatically added to the DatagridView's row when control is Data Bound

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, rows

I have this code that transfers contents from one DataGridView to another DataGridView

```
DailyRecordDataGridView.Columns.Clear()
    For Each Col As DataGridViewColumn In datagrid_log2.Columns
        DailyRecordDataGridView.Columns.Add(DirectCast(Col.Clone, DataGridViewColumn))
    Next
    For rowIndex As Integer = 0 To (datagrid_log2.Rows.Count - 1)
        DailyRecordDataGridView.Rows.Add(datagrid_log2.Rows(rowIndex).Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).Select(Function(c) c.Value).ToArray)
    Next
```

But it shows
**"Rows cannot programmatically added to DataGridView's when the control is data bound"**

Comment: If the control is bound to a data source, add the records to that backing data source.

Comment: Let me try that :)